# Provide command with value in response as a link by Telegram Bot

Tags: hyperlink, telegram-bot

When a user sends a command e.g. **/new_items** to the bot then it replies back with newest 5 items and at the end shows a text as **/new-items 5** for paging (which if send to bot will result in sending back next 5 items). When **/new-items 5** is shown to user then only **/new-items** is shown as link i.e. without **5**. When user clicks on it then it is send to bot I want to make **/new-items 5** as a link so that when user clicks on it then bot receives **/new-items 5** and understands that it has to return next 5 results from starting from 6 to 10.

Comment: Updating sentence. When user clicks on it then it is send to bot. I want to make **/new-items 5** as a link so that when user clicks on it then bot receives **/new-items 5** and understands that it has to return next 5 results starting from 6 (records 6 to 10).

Answer (score -1):

Simply use [custom keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) for this. For python, look at MusicBot example from [aiotg](https://github.com/szastupov/aiotg) library.